# Getting a new disk to be included in the partition of a pre-existing disk on Windows 11

Tags: windows, partitioning, ssd, disk-management

I am looking to buy a new M.2 Samsung SSD for my laptop that already has an M.2 Samsung SSD in it. My current SSD is 500GB while I intend to buy a 1TB one for the new SSD. I plan to use both SSDs together however I'm confused about how I should partition the disks after installing the SSDs.

I have already installed Windows on my current SSD and it's already split into a C: partition for system files and programs, and a D: partition for games and such.

**My questions are:**

- Is it possible to get the new SSD to be included in the D: partition without formatting the current SSD and if so, how?
- How similar do the SSDs have to be? (They will be the same brand and they will be both NVMe M.2)

Comment: Your not going to be able to add a secondary disk and extend the secondary partition you simply will have a third partition.

Comment: it would be a bad idea anyway because you double the chance you'll lose dat if one of the drives fails.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering the questions :

> Is it possible to get the new SSD to be included in the D: partition without formatting the current SSD and if so, how?

No, you can't create a partition that includes more than one disk.

> How similar do the SSDs have to be? (They will be the same brand and they will be both NVMe M.2)

There is no need for the disks to be identical or even similar.

---

You should look for a different solution. Some possibilities are :

- Buy a 2 TB disk and clone your current disk to it, enlarging the
  partition(s) that you wish to have more space
- Move your D: partition to the new disk and remove it from the
  old disk, then extend C:
- Create a partition E: on the new disk and use it for new stuff.